# How to Switch Between two Animations in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

i have a horse with two animations ( run and walk ) in my scene

normally the horse is walking using (walk) animation

i need When the player approaches from the horse, the horse escapes using (run ) animation instead of (walk) animation

anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Additionally, I would suggest making changes to your question to include some code of what you have tried so far to increase your chances of getting a response.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Blend Tree Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) and there is a lot of tutorials about how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with making 2 animations - assuming you already did that. You probably have an Animator on the horse, if not, create one and put it both the animations. After you've created the Animator, open it up by going to Window -> Animator.

In the animator make sure "walk" animation is the layer default state
[image: Animator]
- if it isn't right click the animation and click "Set as layer default state".

Now go to the parameters tab on the right of the Animator window and click the '+' button:
[image: parameters tab - Animator]

and pick 'Trigger' (or Bool/Float) then give it a name, I'll name it 'trigger_run'.

Now right click on an animation state and select 'Make transition' and left-click on the other animation - do the same for the other animation.
Click on the arrow that goes from 'walk' to 'run' and add a condition (on the right). It will automatically add the trigger_run. (Make sure not to put the condition on the arrow back to walk animation.

Enter your script you have on the horse (if not, create one) and create a reference to its Animator and trigger the animation switch:

```
private Animator anim;

void Start() {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update() {

    // CODE

    anim.SetTrigger("trigger_run");

    // CODE

}
```

If you're being confronted with an animation-switch delay go to the 'walk' -> 'run' arrow in your animator and disable 'Has Exit Time', 'Fixed Duration' and put 'Transition Duration (%)' to 0.

[image: animation-switch delay]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer .. i have applied all the steps but unfortunately now the horse always running .. he no longer walks .. I have made sure that the animation walk is the default state .. what can i do ?